# Prestashop webservice add product's tags and attachment document

Tags: web-services, prestashop-1.6

How I can add `tags` in a product using prestashop webservice api? 
I need a a function in this way:

```
function addTagToProduct((int)$ProductId, (string)$tagname){}
```

The same for `attachment document`: what shall I pass to webservice for add those ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use this function for add tags to my product:

```
public function getTagId($Tag){
    //if tag exists
    $xml = $this->get(array('url' => $this->url . '/api/tags?filter[name]='.$Tag.'&limit=1'));
    $resources = $xml -> children() -> children();
    if(!empty($resources)){
        $attributes = $resources->tag->attributes();
        return $attributes['id'];
    }

    //if not exists, add it
    $xml = $this->get(array('url' => $this->url . '/api/tags?schema=synopsis'));
    $resources = $xml -> children() -> children();

    unset($resources->id);
    $resources->name        = $Tag;
    $resources->id_lang     = $this->getIdLang();

    $opt = array(
        'resource' => 'tags',
        'postXml'  => $xml->asXML()
    );

    $xml = $this->add($opt);
    return $xml->tag->id;
}
```

Hope it help.